# JSF, Display FTP download link taken from a bean method

Tags: jsf

I have a "String getFileLocation();" method in my mbean. I need to display the FTP link which is generated by this method on my JSF page. When the link is clicked the standard "Save As" dialog should appear. Also the page must not get reloaded before/after that. Can you please give some advices on how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Save As" dialog is not part of JSF (neither of HTML), it is just the web browser recognizing that the incoming data is not HTML and popping up the options.

Just put a link in your page with a target to a new window.